# Find last row, copy data above and save as CSV

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to use VBA to automatically create data set and save as CSV. I have one Dynamic_Data sheet filled with formulaes which filled when inputs from Sheetlist worksheet given. As per the formula, It can be 50 rows or 500 rows. I want to save only data that has been calculated and now have values in it. But I am not getting last row value and whole worksheet have been saved which also have lot of blank rows or rows with zero value after actual data.
Please help correcting the script.
Here is the code I used.

```
Sub CompileBPData()

Dim s As String
Dim sname As String
Dim StartName As String
Dim EndName As String
Dim MidName As String
Dim StartNum As String
Dim EndNum As String
Dim CoverNum1 As String
Dim CoverNum2 As String
Dim Cover As String
Dim IntMax As String
Dim GetNewSuffix As String
Dim Job As String
Dim Book As String
Dim EA As String
Dim Lrow As Long
On Error Resume Next
GetNewSuffix = " ("
IntMax = ") "
StartName = "Book "
EndName = "Job_"
MidName = "-"

Sheets("Sheetlist").Select
' Open dialouge box for selecting header
Job = InputBox("Enter Job Number")
If Job = "" Then
  Exit Sub
  End If
s = InputBox("Enter Next Book Number")
If s = "" Then
  Exit Sub
End If
Range("D2").Value = s

Book = InputBox("How many Books in One Column")
If Book = "" Then
  Exit Sub
  End If
Range("H3").Value = Book
EA = InputBox("EA Code & Name Please")
If EA = "" Then
  Exit Sub
End If
Range("I8").Value = EA

'******Finding Last row with no value*********
With wsInpt.Columns("E").SpecialCells(Type:=xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Lrow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
End With
'Lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'**********Select Data Sheet and create Paper Data *********

Sheets("Sheetlist").Select
Range("E2").Select
StartNum = Range("E2")
EndNum = Range("E7")
CoverNum1 = Range("D2")
CoverNum2 = Range("E9")
Cover = Range("I2")
Sheets("Dynamic_Data").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=EA & MidName & StartName & CoverNum1 & MidName & CoverNum2 & GetNewSuffix & "G" & StartNum & MidName & "G" & EndNum & IntMax & Cover & " " & StartName & "_" & EndName & Job, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveSheet.Name = "Dynamic_Data"
Sheets("Sheetlist").Select
Range("D2").Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Coud you please attach the data file sample that you working on?

Comment: The file is heavy. Please find download link. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2d9342807051f7f279a9d22b70c6216420201205123610/1f1d23f3c5e08cfe300ae35064fc70b120201205123650/bf48ab

Comment: What's about the below-proposed solution. Lookin (EDITED PART)

Answer (score 1):

**Hope** this could help you.

```
Sub CompileBPData()
Dim s As String
Dim sname As String
Dim StartName As String
Dim EndName As String
Dim MidName As String
Dim StartNum As String
Dim EndNum As String
Dim CoverNum1 As String
Dim CoverNum2 As String
Dim Cover As String
Dim IntMax As String
Dim GetNewSuffix As String
Dim Job As String
Dim Book As String
Dim EA As String
Dim Lrow As Long
On Error Resume Next
GetNewSuffix = " ("
IntMax = ") "
StartName = "Book "
EndName = "Job_"
MidName = "-"

Sheets("Sheetlist").Select
' Open dialouge box for selecting header
Job = InputBox("Enter Job Number")
If Job = "" Then
  Exit Sub
  End If
s = InputBox("Enter Next Book Number")
If s = "" Then
  Exit Sub
End If
Range("D2").Value = s

Book = InputBox("How many Books in One Column")
If Book = "" Then
  Exit Sub
  End If
Range("H3").Value = Book
EA = InputBox("EA Code & Name Please")
If EA = "" Then
  Exit Sub
End If
Range("I8").Value = EA

'******Finding Last row with no value*********
With wsInpt.Columns("E").SpecialCells(Type:=xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Lrow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
End With
'Lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'**********Select Data Sheet and create Paper Data *********

Sheets("Sheetlist").Select
Range("E2").Select
StartNum = Range("E2")
EndNum = Range("E7")
CoverNum1 = Range("D2")
CoverNum2 = Range("E9")
Cover = Range("I2")

'------------------ BEGIN OF EDITED PART --------------------------------
'Loop Until Calculation is Done
Do
    DoEvents
Loop While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone

'Find Last ROW
Dim LastRow As Double

  LastRow = 60001 ' <-- NOTE!: YOU MUST PUT HERE MAX ROWS NUMBER ))
Do
  LastRow = LastRow - 1
Loop Until Worksheets("Dynamic_Data").Range("A" & LastRow).Value <> 0

MsgBox "LastRow= " & LastRow

'Copy the Range of Data
  Worksheets("Dynamic_Data").Range("A1:AB" & LastRow).Copy

'Save the CSV File
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'IT WORKS TO DISABLE ALERT PROMPT
    Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With tempWB
        .Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .SaveAs Filename:=EA & MidName & StartName & CoverNum1 & MidName & CoverNum2 & GetNewSuffix & "G" & StartNum & MidName & "G" & EndNum & IntMax & Cover & " " & StartName & "_" & EndName & Job, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
    End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'RESETS DISPLAY ALERTS
'------------------ END OF EDITED PART --------------------------------

ActiveSheet.Name = "Dynamic_Data"
Sheets("Sheetlist").Select
Range("D2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This is really helpful. This solved most of the issues. One more request I have.If I change "No. of books in one column" to "Last book No.", it will populate data till the last number. There are chances that the all the columns are not evenly filled. How to check that?